# Bootstrap accordion PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap accordion with links pointing to different pages.

ex:

```
<div class="accordion-group"> 
    <div class="accordion-heading"> 
        <a href="#acc1" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#side_accordion" data-toggle="collapse"> 
            <i class="icon-folder-close"></i> 
            Profile
        </a> 
    </div> 

    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="acc1"> 
        <div class="accordion-inner "> 
            <ul class="nav nav-list" > 
                <li class="active"><a href="addprofile.html" >Add Profile</a></li> 
                <li><a href="updateprofile.html"  >Update Profile</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="accordion-group"> 
    <div class="accordion-heading"> 
        <a href="#acc2" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#side_accordion" data-toggle="collapse"> 
            <i class="icon-file"></i> 
            Photo
        </a> 
    </div> 

    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="acc2"> 
        <div class="accordion-inner"> 
            <ul class="nav nav-list"> 
                <li><a href="addphoto" >Add Photo</a></li> 
                <li><a href="updatephoto">Update Photo</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Now when i click on some item, it is redirected to the page but state of accordion is lost.

Any idea on how i can preserve the state of accordion. When i click on 'Add photo' and that is opened i want the photos accordion to be opened and 'Add Photo' with dark background.

I'm using PHP for server side code.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re expecting? You have a link to an external page—clicking it is going to take you to that page.

Comment: you might need a 'sticky accordion' using cookies http://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-and-cookies

Comment: @MartinBean  When i'm in 'Add Photo' page, i want the Photos accordion to be automatically opened. You got me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing data-target attributes. See docs http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, they are different pages. For ex: Add photo is an external page.